# How to easily change Visual Studio 2022 Editor Font and Colors to match VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I appreciate that the Visual Studio team is continually trying to improve the VS environment for developers.  However, I find the fonts and colors used in the VS 2022 editor to be too loud and mentally taxing.  I'd very much like to change the VS 2022 text editor fonts and colors to match what I'm use to in VS 2019.

Unfortunately it's not a simple as going into Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors and changing the font from `Cascadia Code` back to `Consolas`. Sure one can do that, and that's a step forward but the font coloring is then to light.  This is apparently because the font colors in general were lightened in VS 2022 to partially compensate for the fact that `Cascadia Code` is a very heavy font.  This of course makes sense, **IF** you want to keep `Cascadia Code` as the editor font.  But I don't.  I want to switch back to `Consolas`, and I'd like the font coloring that VS 2019 used as well.

So anybody know an easy way to get the VS 2022 editor to use the text color coding that VS 2019 uses?

Comment: Tools > Import and Export > Export, untick everything except "Font and Colors".  Import the generated file in VS2022.  No idea if that's a solid procedure, but worth a shot.

Comment: @HansPassant In theory should work.  VS 2019 says it exports the Fonts and Colors settings without error, and VS2022 says it imports them without error.  But alas, the fonts and colors in VS2022 don't change. Exports from VS2022 when reimported into VS2022 do change fonts and colors. But that doesn't get me what I need. ;-)

Comment: This article might be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-change-fonts-and-colors-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 7):

I was able to figure it out in my VS 2022 environment. Font now looks identical to my VS 2019 IDE.

VS 2022 > Tools > Options > Environment > Font and Colors > Change font to "Consolas" size 10.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using the dark theme in VS 2019, you can install this port: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.DarkTheme2019, works great for me. Unfortunately it doesn't look like anyone ported the light theme.

Comment: The answer is not in context to the question, as the question is about the software and the answer is about an extension

Comment: Unfortunately I use the light theme.  But this is a creative solution for people using the dark theme even if it does require an add on.

Comment: @YashKaranke _"The answer is not in context to the question, as the question is about the software and the answer is about **an extension**"_ - incorrect.  Visual Studio 2022 now supports _Themes_ which are configured by _installable theme extensions_.   _["Then, navigate to the Tools -> Themes dropdown. This list of themes will include the name of your newly installed theme. Select that theme to apply it to Visual Studio."](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/custom-themes/)_.

Comment: @YashKaranke also please note _["The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include **“try this instead**”"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)_

Comment: This extension just broke my VS 2022. Error messages everywhere. No I'm trying to remove it.